# unir 4 consultas de una misma tabla en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, select, union

Hola comunidad necesito de su apoyo como dice el titulo necesito unir 4 consultas de una misma en una sola consulta, tengo la siguiente tabla 'productos' :

| id | codigo | marca | modelo | calidad | estado_merma | fecha | estado_vendido |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 000001 | lg | xpro | alta | 1 | m/d/a | 0 |
| 324 | 000002 | lg | xpro | alta | 0 | m/d/a | 1 |
| 345 | 000003 | lg | xpro | baja | 0 | m/d/a | 1 |
| 347 | 000004 | lg | xpro | baja | 1 | m/d/a | 0 |
| 348 | 000005 | xiaomi | poco | alta | 1 | m/d/a | 1 |

- estado_merma: hace referencia si el producto esta defectuoso o no ( 1=optimo, 0=defectuoso).
- estado_vendido: hace referencia si el producto a sido vendido o no (1=disponible, 0=vendido).

**NECESTO AGRUPARLOS POR marca,modelo,calidad  DE ACUERDO A ESO mostrar la cantidad, vendidos, merma y stock.**

CONSULTA PARA MOSTRAR marca,modelo,calidad y cantidad:

```
SELECT marca,modelo,calidad, COUNT(*) AS cantidad 
FROM productos  
GROUP BY marca,modelo,calidad;
```

CONSULTA para mostrar vendidos:

```
SELECT marca,modelo,calidad, COUNT(*) AS vendidos 
FROM productos  
WHERE estado_logico=0 
GROUP BY marca,modelo,calidad;
```

CONSULTA PARA MOSTRAR MERMA:

```
SELECT marca,modelo,calidad, COUNT(*) AS merma 
FROM productos  WHERE estado=0 
GROUP BY marca,modelo,calidad;
```

CONSULTA PARA MOSTRAR STOCK:

```
SELECT marca,modelo,calidad, COUNT(*) AS stock 
FROM productos WHERE estado_logico=1 AND estado=1 GROUP BY marca,modelo,calidad;
```

UNIENDO LAS 4 CONSULTAS obtendria algo como esto :

| marca | modelo | calidad | cantidad | vendidos | merma | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lg | xpro | alta | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| lg | xpro | baja | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| xiaomi | poco | alta | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes agrupar las 4 consultas en una sola utilizando la sentencia `CASE`. En cada caso si se cumple la condición especificada el resultado será 1, null en caso contrario; luego sumas o cuentas los 1.

```
SELECT marca,
       modelo,
       calidad, 
       COUNT(*) AS cantidad,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN estado_vendido = 0 THEN 1 END) AS vendidos,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN estado_merma = 0 THEN 1 END) AS merma,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN estado_vendido = 1 AND estado_merma = 1 THEN 1 END) AS stock
FROM productos  
GROUP BY marca, modelo, calidad;
```

Comment: @nachospiru     Muchas gracias por tu aporte me fue de gran ayuda, funcionó perfectamente.

Comment: De nada @junioralvarez, me alegro que mi query te haya ayudado. No olvides seleccionar la respuesta para que tu pregunta quede como respondida.